# Can dogs shed back to their original coats?

Tags: dogs, shedding, biology

We have a schnoodle and his coat changed from black to silver by his first birthday, just like other pups I’ve read in some previous threads. Now he’s aged to 14 years now and he’s starting to spot jet black more often, with bigger spots like when he was a pup, except it was silver then. Is this a generational thing that he sheds back to his original coat?

Comment: this question is related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9989/is-it-normal-for-a-dogs-coat-to-change-color

Answer (score 1):

I've had a multiple breed of dogs throughout my life, and most of them keep changing their colors with time. Your dog may or may not go back to the exact shade he was before, rather he may develop a new mix of colors. It is always surprising to see what new colors emerge on their fur from time to time.